# How to set Airflow trigger rule when certain upstream tasks of all succeed?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have [task a], [task b], [task c] as upstream tasks to tigger downstream [task d].

I would like to set up a trigger rule when all task a, b, c done, and task a & b have to succeed, regardless of whether task c fail or succeed (but task c has to be done).

Would it possible to do so and how? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Airflow [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules) allow to set some conditions on which tasks are triggered depending on results of previous task. Unfortunately there is no possibility to fine-tune this and specify exact logic of individual task result (like task `a` and `b` needs to succeed, while task `c` result can be ignored).

You can implement your desired behavior with the help of a dummy operator:

```
a = PythonOperator(task_id='a', python_callable=lambda: print("Hello from a"))
b = PythonOperator(task_id='b', python_callable=lambda: print("Hello from b"))
c = PythonOperator(task_id='c', python_callable=lambda: print(f"Hello from {1/0}"))
c_catch = EmptyOperator(task_id='c_catch', trigger_rule="all_done")
d = PythonOperator(task_id='d', python_callable=lambda: print("Hello from d"))

[a, b] >> d
c >> c_catch >> d
```

[image]

Here task `d` depends on `a`, `b` and *indirectly* on `c`, where `c_catch` is only responsible for catching `c`'s result and pretending it was a success.